# Finding extrema of function

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

We have the function $$f_a(x)=\frac{a-x}{\ln (a-x)}, \ a\in \mathbb{R}$$

To get the domain of that function we have to consider the following restrictions: $$\begin{cases}\ln (a-x)\neq 0 \\ a-x>0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} a-x\neq 1 \\ a-x>0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x\neq a-1 \\ x<a \end{cases}$$ So the domain is $$D_f=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x<a \ \text{ and } x\neq a-1\}$$ Is this correct?

The function has to root since $f_a=0 \Rightarrow a-x=0 \Rightarrow x=a\notin D_f$, right?

Next, I want to determine the extremas. The first derivative is $$f_a'=\frac{-\ln (a-x)+1}{\left (\ln (a-x)\right )^2}$$ The root of the first derivative is $x=a-e$.

To check if this is a minimum or a maximum we need the second derivative, which is at $x=a-e$ positive, so we have a minimum.

Is everything correct so far?

Is this the only extremum or do we have to check also the points where the functions is not defined, i.e. $x=a$ and $x=a-1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct so far, but in order to complete your study of the global/local extrema you should also evaluate the limits at the boundary of the domain $D_f$,
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x),\quad \lim_{x\to (a-1)^-}f(x),\quad \lim_{x\to (a-1)^+}f(x),\quad \lim_{x\to a^-}f(x).$$
Are you interested also to determine the convexity/concavity of $f$? Then you need to discuss the sign of $f''$ in $D_f$.

Comment: We have the limits $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=+\infty,\quad \lim_{x\to (a-1)^-}f(x)=-\infty,\quad \lim_{x\to (a-1)^+}f(x)=+\infty,\quad \lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=0$$ or not? So do we havealso a minimum at $x=a$ ?

Comment: We have that $\lim_{x\to (a-1)^-}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to (a-1)^+}f(x)=-\infty$the others are correct. No $x=a$ is not a local extrema point because it is not in $D_f$. $x=a$ is a maximum local point id we extend $f$ at $x=0$. $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ limits imply that there are no global minima. So you have just a local minimum at $a-e$.

Comment: Why do wee have a maximum at $x=a$ ? Could you explain to me that part further?

Comment: I meant **if we extend $f$ at $a$** with the value $0$. Then $f$ is continuous in $(a-1,a]$ and there the derivative $f'$ is positive that is $f$ is increasing in $(a-1,a)$ and therefore $a$ is a local maximum.

Without the exiension $a$ is not a local extrema because $a\not \in D_f$.

Comment: @MaryStar Any further doubt? Looking at your recent questions it seems that you forgot that you have the opportunity to vote and/or accept one of the given answers.

Answer (score 1):

The function tends to $\pm\infty$ in the points the functions is not defined therefore the point you attained is **the only local minima**. To check this graphically, you can refer to  [The graph of $\Large {-x\over \ln (-x)}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5ty9obeknw)

Comment: Do we not have $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=0$ ?

Comment: Yes we have but the function is not even defined in $x=a$ but there we can define  supremum instead of maxima. You also can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima